# Java: weird behavior of conditional operator

Tags: java, conditional-operator

I have a very simple java class to solve Decode ways using recursive approach. I am seeing this weird behavior of conditional operator,

```
package decodeways;

public class Solution {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(numDecodings("1456"));
  }
  
  public static int numDecodings(String s) {
    if(s.length()>0 && s.charAt(0)=='0') 
      return 0;
    if(s.length()==0) return 1;
    if(s.length()==1)
      return 1;
    
    int num1 = s.charAt(0)-'0';
    int num2 = s.charAt(1)-'0';
    int one = numDecodings(s.substring(1));
    int two = s.length()>1?numDecodings(s.substring(2)):0;
    int res = one 
        + num1<3 && num2<7 ? two:0;
    return res;
  }
}
```

if I put a parentheses, `(num1<3 && num2<7 ? two:0)`  then everything is well and good but if I remove the parentheses, then getting incorrect results.

during the process of debugging, **one** will be computed to 1 and **two** will be computed to 1 and **res** will be 1 as well with parentheses but without it, the computed result of res will be 0 (screnshot attached) which is the source of error.
[image]
I am aware of the operator precedence in java, but in this situation I can't figure out why it shows incorrect behavior, because in the below code:

```
int res = one 
        + num1<3 && num2<7 ? two:0;
```

one + num1<3 is illegal
So, java is intelligent enough to not confuse between (one + num1<3) and (num2<7 ? two:0) to be consider separately.
So, as per my understanding the only legal observable behavior for java compiler is to automatically consider `num1<3 && num2<7 ? two:0` as an atomic operation(Please correct me if I am wrong), irrespective of parentheses is available or not.

Please guide me to have a better understanding.

Thanks.

Comment: The behaviour of the [tag:conditional-operator] doesn't have anything to do with [tag:recursive-datastructures]. Tag accurately and not indiscriminately. Don't post pictures of text here.

Comment: @user It doesn't have anything to do with [tag:recursion] either. The OP's code might have to do with recursion, but the operator doesn't.

Comment: @pkm You posted pictures of your program. Your program is text. Post the text directly. Making the picture and posting that is a complete waste of your time and our bandwidth.

Answer (score 4):

```
int res = one 
        + num1<3 && num2<7 ? two:0;
```

is equivalent to

```
int res = (((one + num1) < 3) && (num2 < 7)) ? two : 0;
```

Everything before `?` is included in the boolean expression, since the ternary/conditional operator has the lowest precedence here (not including the assignment operator) and `+` has the highest.

The order goes something like:

- `+`, so `one + num1` is put together first
- `<`, so now there's `(one + num1) < 3` and `num2 < 7`
- `&&`, after which you have `((one + num1) < 3) && (num2 < 7)`
- and *finally* `?:`

You seem to be expecting the newline to make the compiler think `one` and `num1<3 && num2<7 ? two:0` are separate, but it actually just ignores all whitespace. Putting the parentheses there is the only way to make sure `one` is added to the whatever the conditional operator evaluates to.

```
int res = one + (num1 < 3 && num2 < 7 ? two : 0);
```